# Review audit question deleted

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I was asked to review the following answer by a new user: [Call ***.java*** file from .html file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1419082) (note java, not js), and so I attempted to edit the answer, as it was technically accurate, but was badly phrased and incomplete.

On attempting to edit the question I was informed that it had been deleted, and so I marked it as no further action needed (as action had already been taken). I was then told I had failed an audit question.

My question is this - at what point should we no longer attempt to salvage an answer which is technically accurate, especially when we have has to do some (admittedly not much) research to verify its accuracy?

Comment: Did you try to edit the question or the answer?

Comment: There's nothing accurate about that answer, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Comment: @hims056 the answer, as that's what I was supposed to be reviewing

Comment: @Yannis that's javascript, not java

Comment: @BiggAl Read the manual a bit more carefully, it explains how to bind android code (java) with javascript, in order to be able to call it from HTML - the answer your reviewed claims that's impossible. Also check the question itself, the question isn't about if it's possible or not, but why it stopped working when OP updated the SDK.

Comment: @Yannis that still has to be a compiled class, no? In this case it was the question that was confusing by using terminology incorrectly, although I must admit to a brain-fart in not having read the first line very well

Comment: The question's title is horrible indeed, something that was [pointed out in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501059/call-java-file-from-html-file-in-android#comment20212168_14501059) (wonder why no one edited it though). Still the answer should answer the question, not just its title. That said, the audit was a bit tricky.

Comment: @BiggAl How did you try to edit it? By clicking the "edit" link via the review page, or did you try to click through to the post itself in order to edit?

Comment: The former, then the latter - the answer no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this - at what point should we no longer attempt to salvage an answer which is technically accurate, especially when we have has to do some (admittedly not much) research to verify its accuracy?

In my opinion, there is no predefined limit, you define your own limits. Do you want to try to salvage a post, even if it's terrible? Great, go ahead!

Don't be discouraged by failing that review audit. It was intended for people who blindly click the same button in the review queues, without paying attention to the contents presented to them. The system was probably expecting that you added a comment or flag, instead of editing. Maybe it could also disclose it's an audit as soon as you click the edit button, and let you pass. You can add that as a feature-request, if you wish.

Comment: It was moderator deleted where I think the system considered the action it as a failure because you know, moderators are never wrong.  :)

Comment: I think that answer was added as an audit case *exactly* because a moderator had previously deleted it.

Comment: Ah yes, the dates on the deletion and review tell the tale.  It was deleted in the past and the review was fairly recent.